# Как менять прозрачность в зависимости от значения прокрученных пикселей?

Tags: javascript

Хочу, например, каждые 300px выводить старый заголовок и вводить новый меняя прозрачность, которая зависит от того, в какую сторону я скролю([пример](http://davegamache.com/parallax/))?
Расскажите пожалуйста, а лучше покажите, как, допустим,  из значения `1234` которое возвращает `window.pageYOffset` получать значения от `0` до `1`.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var headings = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

for (let i = 1; i < headings.length; i++) {
  headings[i].style.opacity = 0;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  // ??????
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 3000px;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>one</h1>
  <h1>two</h1>
  <h1>three</h1>
  <h1>four</h1>
  <h1>five</h1>
</div>
```

Ещё не пойму, условие ведь такое должно быть?

```
   if(window.pageYOffset < 300) {
     // change opacity
   }

   if(window.pageYOffset > 300 && window.pageYOffset < 600) {
     // change opacity
   }

   ....
   ....
   ....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как-то так?

```js
var headings = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var d = document.documentElement;
  // приводим значение скролла к интервалу [0-1]
  upd(d.scrollTop / (d.scrollHeight - d.clientHeight))
});

upd(0) 

// функция обновления, входной аргумент тут - число в интервале от 0 до 1
// 0 - непрокрученная страница, 1 - польностью прокрученная вниз страница.
function upd(v) {

  // умножаем на диапазон возможных значений (индексов)
  v *= headings.length - 1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) { 
  
    // расcтояние между текущим элементом и значением скролла в нашем диапазоне
    let d = Math.abs(i - v); 
    
    // вычисляем значение прозрачности, как 1 минус расстояние
    // тут браузер не ругается при opacity<0, поэтому к диапазону 0-1 можно не приводить 
    headings[i].style.opacity = 1 - d; 
    headings[i].style.transform = `scale(${1 - i + v})`
  }
}
```

```css
* {margin: 0}

body {height: 3000px}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>one</h1>
  <h1>two</h1>
  <h1>three</h1>
  <h1>four</h1>
  <h1>five</h1>
</div>
```

---

Вариант без наложения:

```js
let headings = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

let upd = v => {
  for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) 
    headings[i].style.opacity = 1 - 2*Math.abs(i - v*(headings.length-1));
}

addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let d = document.documentElement;
  upd(d.scrollTop / (d.scrollHeight - d.clientHeight));
});

upd(0)
```

```css
* {margin: 0}

body {height: 3000px}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>one</h1>
  <h1>two</h1>
  <h1>three</h1>
  <h1>four</h1>
  <h1>five</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Опять эта непосильная магия )

Comment: магия посильная. просто никогда нет правильного решения, есть своя логика и вот она уже может завести не туда )